# How to write the following function in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am new to scheme and doing some exercises. I am trying to do the following:
The function i am going to write takes one list parameter (no input check needed). Then it remoces multiple occurences of the elements and returns the new list. Here is an example input-output:Let us call the function "once",

```
=>(once '(1 2 5 2 3 4 2 4 1 2))
=>Value: (1 2 5 3 4)
```

Here is my solution:

```
(define once
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst) 
        '() 
        (if (member (car lst) (cdr lst)) 
            (once (cdr lst)) 
            (cons (car lst) (once (cdr lst)))))))
```

But the order of elements is changed although it eliminates duplicates. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add items from `lst` if they are not in the result.

```
(define (once lst)
  (let looking ((lst lst) (rst '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        (reverse rst)                   ; leave order unchanged
        (let ((nxt (car lst)))
          (looking (cdr lst)
                   (if (member nxt rst) ; nxt in rst
                       rst              ; yes: don't augment rst
                       (cons nxt rst)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define once L
 (if (null? L)
  '()
   (cons (car L) (once (filter (n-eq-x? (car L)) (cdr L))))))

(define (n-eq-x? value)
 (lambda (x) (if (eq? value x) #f #t)))
```

Of you can write it with a helper

```
(define (once L)
 (reverse (once-helper L '())))

(define (once-helper L L-once)
 (cond ((null? L) L-once)
       ((member? (car L) (L-once) 
        (once-helper (cdr L) L-once))
       (else (once-helper (cdr L) (cons (car L) L-once)))))
```

which is closer to the original, the difference here is that instead a building a list with elements that don't appear in the rest of the list, you build a second list, with elements of the original that aren't already members.  The check will turn false if you already have the element, rather than being false if you're going to get the element later.

Answer (score 1):

In Racket, it's as simple as this:

```
(define once remove-duplicates)
(once '(1 2 5 2 3 4 2 4 1 2))
=> '(1 2 5 3 4)
```

But if you have to implement it from scratch, here's the general idea, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (once lst)
  (cond (<???>  ; is the list empty?
         <???>) ; return the empty list
        (<???>  ; is the current element member of the rest of the list?
         <???>) ; advance recursion
        (else   ; otherwise it's not duplicate,
         (cons <???>     ; cons current element
               <???>)))) ; advance recursion
```

Comment: Is this a built-in function? Thanks but i am trying to write it on my own.

Comment: @bigO yes, it's built-in in Racket. If you need to implement it yourself, it's rather simple: iterate over the list asking if the current element is a `member` in the rest of the list. If it is member, then continue with the cdr of the list (it's duplicate). If it is not a member, then cons it (it's not duplicate). Either way, advance the recursion

Comment: Thanks, actually, i did it, but this time the order of the elements are changed. Can you see my edited question?

Comment: That's the way the output comes out, because only the last occurrence of an element is preserved. One quick and dirty solution would be to reverse the lists like this: `(reverse (once (reverse '(1 2 5 2 3 4 2 4 1 2))))`. Use a helper procedure if required.

Comment: ... But check with your instructor first. I wouldn't mind if the output comes out in a different order, as long as it's correct

Answer (score 1):

As you process the input list, you have an element at the head of the list, and the remaining tail of the list.

1. If the element at the head of the list is in the tail, then you don't need to add it to the result since it will be caught in a later iteration.
2. If the element at the head of the list is not in the tail, push it onto the result.
3. Recurse.